# What is the effect of setting meta viewport tag with `height=device-height`?

Tags: html, ios, cordova, mobile, responsive

I understand that the default behavior of iOS regarding `device-width` might be to try to render websites using a viewport width of 980px, and setting `width=device-width` might be useful (particularly if you are developping a Cordova/mobileApp/SPA.

However I'm not sure to understand when should we set `height=device-height`. Does adding this line have any effect? Isn't it the default behavior to use the device height as the viewport height?

I have a mobile app, that is available both as a mobile website and a cordova native app. There are 2 separate `index.html` pages with different settings (legacy):

// Mobile website has:

// Cordova has:

I'd like to know the risks I encounter of using the same content value for both cases (which seems like it's mostly arround `device-height`)

I didn't find the [online documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to be really helpful on that subject. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

The online documentation you linked does point to the specs:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#width-and-height-properties

**device-width** and **device-height** translate to 100vw and 100vh respectively

Comment: But what I'd like to know is what is the default value of `device-height` if we don't set it?

Comment: Technically **device-height** is value not a property. 

So you can set **height** to the value of **device-height**, else **height** defaults to **auto**. More info at https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#height-desc

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, I was talking about setting `height`. What effect does it have to set it to `heigh=device-height` VS not setting any `height` value. Auto = ?

Comment: So setting **height** to **device-width** ensures you are setting your viewport to the height of the device rather than the rendered space. It behaves exactly like **width**. In my projects it seems adding *width* is enough but you always have the option to be more explicit if you want.

Comment: Then what is the size of the default rendered space? on iOS not setting it seems to means width will be `980px` for example. What does it mean to not set `device-height`